# Store and parse array in model in Waterline

Tags: arrays, json, sails.js, waterline

Using the newest version of Waterline `0.13.1-6` standalone.

The `array` type no longer exist in this version. So I assume the way to store arrays is now to use the `JSON` type.

Sample of my model `Model`:

```
  attributes: {
    someArray: { type: 'json' }
  }
```

Problem: on an instance of `Model`, `model.someArray` is now a String. I should `JSON.parse` it each time I request one to get the values in the array. That's very not convenient and can obviously lead to errors.

Is there a built-in way in the new Waterline to make this clean (automatically parse JSON fields...)?

Comment: Are you getting only the array field in string format, or the whole response?

Comment: Only the array field (any JSON field I define, actually); the model object itself (and the non-JSON properties) are working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are fine to use JSON as you are suggesting. No need to parse it, this is done automatically when you do your meta fetch or find. You can do

`YourModel.create({someArray: [1,2,3]}).meta({fetch: true}).then( out => {
    console.log(out.someArray[0]); //1;
});`

I would have some other identifying attribute for finding it, like say myRef: {type: 'string'}

Then you can do

`YourModel.find({myRef: 'something'}).limit(1).then( out => {
console.log(out[0].someArray[1]); //2
});`

Comment: Great answer!  Side note: as of the latest Sails v1 release (and waterline@0.13.1-4), you can now also use [`.fetch()`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/f4858b0d3c6bb80bc130060ecdd428e735ec111e/reference/waterline/queries/fetch.md) as a shortcut for `.meta({fetch:true})`

Comment: Sorry for the late answer but I don't get it. The doc said that this option is to return the modified values when doing an update. It does not say anything about parsing JSON field when using a find()... Aside: my models are already created (without meta fetch). How can I use find to read their JSON fields correctly?

Comment: Okay it appears that some values from my base where encoded as string containing a JSON... error from legacy storage I guess. I mark this as answered anyway.